# React beautiful DND wait for state change before dragging

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm trying to create a project that mimics monday.com (inspiration) and I'm using react beautiful DND to make all the drag and drop.

What happens is, whenever I drag a group (Draggable) I also change a  state, which "collapses" all groups, and changes their height.

The problem with that, is that the DND calculates the indices of the groups inside their container (Droppable) and when I change their height, it gets all scrambled up.

Is there a way to fix this? I thought maybe I could wait for react to render and only then start the drag, but I couldn't make it work